# Could not find the css font-size changing trigger in below case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

During the First time or page refresh loading the font-size is totally different (Bigger) than the font-size after resize (smaller).

I've debugged for a long time, have tried using either px or em, but the font-size changing effect is so dramatic after re-sizing behavior,not in a gradually changing form that i expected. There is no specifically defined Javascript to change font-size in this case as coding all from scratch.

I've also given the to make the question as featured as possible to debug; 
(sorry, I've removed the link as the issue has been settled the real answer is below)

Initially, my purpose is to use 'em' relative font-size and let the font-size auto change bit by bit with the decreasing of the device width; 
Now it's not going as i expected and I'm searching for the reasons.

summary(font-end frameworks used are listed as below)

jQuery, jQuery-ui, bootstrap 3, fullpage.js, bigvideo.js

Comment: Offhand it looks like a screen re-draw issue.

Comment: Probably unrelated but you are loading both the minified and non-minified version of JQuery

Comment: also thanks for pointing out my double loading of script, the issue is caused by fullPage.js default option 
resize:true  that I missed to turn off;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using fullPage.js and you don't want the plugin to modify your text you should set the option `resize` to `false` as it is active by default:

Use `resize:false`.

From [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options):

> **resize:** (default true) Whether you want to resize the text when the window is resized.

If you want to have full control over your font size I'd recommend you to use CSS3 media queries.

Comment: That's exactly the trigger to the font-size. now i have enabled this line in the fullPage option. and so true it stops auto re-size by itself.

Comment: and i will take your advice using @media quires to do precise font-size control, which seems better than the "em" font-size used by fullPage.js demo pages.